# function that returns the last met of each numbers in a sorted array

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I wrote a function that returns the first met of each numbers from 0 to 9

```
array = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]


def lower(a, val, left, right):
    if left == right:
        return left
    mid = (left + right) // 2

    if a[mid] < val:
        return lower(a, val, mid+1, right)
    else:
        return lower(a, val, left, mid)

for i in range(10):
    print(lower_bound(array, i , 0, len(array)-1), end =' ')
```

result: 0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 .

I tried to write a function that return the last met of each numbers from 0 to 9. and wanted to get:
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

But it does not works correctly(
could you help me to with it?
Here is my function.

```
def upper(a, val, left, right):

    if left == right:
        return left
    mid = (left + right) // 2

    if a[mid] <= val:
        return upper(a, val, mid+1, right)
    else:
        return upper(a, val, left, mid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `left-1` instead of `left`. This is because when you arrive at the last index of val `mid`, the first if will look from `mid+1` (`upper(a, val, mid+1, right)`)

```py
def upper(a, val, left, right):

    if left == right:
        return left-1
    mid = (left + right) // 2

    if a[mid] <= val:
        return upper(a, val, mid+1, right)
    else:
        return upper(a, val, left, mid)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in every case that you are in the last occurrence and the `right` is one index after, you find the appropriate index but keep moving one more step. the algorithm seems to be good, but just eliminate this case and everything works fine:

```
array = [0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]

def upper(a, val, left, right):

    if left == right:
        if a[left] == val:
            return left
        else:
            return left-1
    mid = (left + right) // 2
    if a[mid] <= val:
        return upper(a, val, mid+1, right)
    else:
        return upper(a, val, left, mid)
        

for i in range(10):
    a = upper(array,i,0,19)
    print(a)
```

output:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

checked it for several others and it works fine I think

Answer (score 1):

Using the floor function when calculating `mid` means the function is not symmetrical. You can't just mirror one part of it without considering the other.

```
def upper(a, val, left, right):
    if left == right:
        return left
    mid = (left + right + 1) // 2

    if a[mid] > val:
        return upper(a, val, left, mid-1)
    else:
        return upper(a, val, mid, right)
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the first met:

```
for i in range(10):
  print(array.index(i))
```

To find the last met:

```
inverted_array = array[::-1]
for i in range(10):
  print(len(array) - 1 - inverted_array.index(i))
```