# XOR of pairwise sum of every unordered pairs in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, bit-manipulation

Question Description : Given an array arr[] of length N, the task is to find the XOR of pairwise sum of every possible unordered pairs of the array.

I solved this question using the method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582903/2034787) post.

My Code :

```
int xorAllSum(int a[], int n)
{
    int curr, prev = 0;
    int ans = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++) {
        int o = 0, z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] & (1 << k)) {
                o++;
            }
            else {
                z++;
            }
        }

        curr = o * z + prev;
        if (curr & 1) {
            ans = ans | (1 << k);
        }
        prev = o * (o - 1) / 2;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Code Descrption : I am finding out at each bit, whether our answer will have that bit set ort not. So to do this for each bit-position, I find the count of all the numbers which have a set bit at the position(represeneted by 'o' in the code) and the count of numbers having un-set bit at that position(represented by 'z').

Now if we pair up these numbers(the numbers having set bit and unset bit together, then we will get a set bit in their sum(Because we need to get XOR of all pair sums).

The factor of 'prev' is included to account for the carry over bits. Now we know that the answer will have a set bit at current position only if the number of set bits are 'odd' as we are doing an XOR operation.

But I am not getting correct output. Can anyone please help me

Test Cases :

1. n = 3, a[] = {1, 2, 3} => (1 + 2) ^ (1 + 3) ^ (2 + 3)

=> 3 ^ 4 ^ 5 = 2

=> Output : 2

2. n = 6

   a[] = {1 2 10 11 18 20}

   Output : 50
3. n = 8

   a[] = {10 26 38 44 51 70 59 20}

   Output : 182

Constraints : 2 <= n <= 10^8

Also, here we need to consider UNORDERED PAIRS and not Ordered Pairs for the answer

PS : I know that the same question has been asked before but I couldn't explain my problem with this much detail in the comments so I created a new post. I am new here, so please pardon me and give me your feedback :)

Comment: For test case 1, shouldn't "2" be the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, 2 is correct.. I have given correct outputs here

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: For test Case 1 my code gives : 6    For test case 2 my code gives: 54

Comment: Are you sure 50 is correct output for test case 2? I am getting 52 with a different implementation. Also, are you barred from using certain implementations or by a certain run-time?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about these test cases. Yeah, the brute force solution is O(n^2). I want to do this in O(n)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the evaluation of ```curr``` is incorrect. Why do you think simply adding ```prev``` solves the purpose?

Comment: Yes, that curr part needs attention. I am adding 'prev' because when we add two numbers to form a pair, then some numbers having both bits '1' will also be added and In am computing their count using prev = o*(o-1)/2. Now due to both bits '1' being added they will come as '1' in the next bit. This 'prev' and 'curr' part is a still a bit unclear to me. But I did as said in the above mentioned post. If u cud refer to it and point out my mistake, that wud me really helpful

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the idea in the [post you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60582903/2034787) is missing important details, if it could work at all with the stated complexity. (I would be happy to better understand and be corrected should that author wish to clarify their method further.)

Here's my understanding of at least one author's [intention](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/74148) for an `O(n * log n * w)` solution, where `w` is the number of bits in the largest sum, as well as JavaScript code with a random comparison to brute force to show that it works (easily translatable to C or Python).

The idea is to examine the contribution of each bit one a time. Since in any one iteration, we are only interested in whether the `k`th bit in the sums is set, we can remove all parts of the numbers that include higher bits, taking them each modulo `2^(k + 1)`.

Now the sums that would necessarily have the `k`th bit set are in the intervals, `[2^k, 2^(k + 1))` (that's when the `k`th bit is the highest) and `[2^(k+1) + 2^k, 2^(k+2) − 2]` (when we have both the `k`th and `(k+1)`th bits set). So in the iteration for each bit, we sort the input list (modulo `2^(k + 1)`), and for each left summand, we decrement a pointer to the end of each of the two intervals, and binary search the relevant start index.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/64082509
// Returns the lowest index of a value
// greater than or equal to the target
function lowerIdx(a, val, left, right){
  if (left >= right)
    return left;
  mid = left + ((right - left) >> 1);
  if (a[mid] < val)
    return lowerIdx(a, val, mid+1, right);
  else
    return lowerIdx(a, val, left, mid);
}

function bruteForce(A){
  let answer = 0;
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++)
    for (let j=0; j<i; j++)
      answer ^= A[i] + A[j];
  return answer;
}
  
function f(A, W){
  const n = A.length;
  const _A = new Array(n);
  let result = 0;

  for (let k=0; k<W; k++){
    for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
      _A[i] = A[i] % (1 << (k + 1));
    _A.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    let pairs_with_kth_bit = 0;
    let l1 = 1 << k;
    let r1 = 1 << (k + 1);
    let l2 = (1 << (k + 1)) + (1 << k);
    let r2 = (1 << (k + 2)) - 2;
    let ptr1 = n - 1;
    let ptr2 = n - 1;

    for (let i=0; i<n-1; i++){
      // Interval [2^k, 2^(k+1))
      while (ptr1 > i+1 && _A[i] + _A[ptr1] >= r1)
        ptr1 -= 1;
      const idx1 = lowerIdx(_A, l1-_A[i], i+1, ptr1);
      let sum = _A[i] + _A[idx1];
      if (sum >= l1 && sum < r1)
        pairs_with_kth_bit += ptr1 - idx1 + 1;

      // Interval [2^(k+1)+2^k, 2^(k+2)−2]
      while (ptr2 > i+1 && _A[i] + _A[ptr2] > r2)
        ptr2 -= 1;
      const idx2 = lowerIdx(_A, l2-_A[i], i+1, ptr2);
      sum = _A[i] + _A[idx2]
      if (sum >= l2 && sum <= r2)
        pairs_with_kth_bit += ptr2 - idx2 + 1;
    }

    if (pairs_with_kth_bit & 1)
      result |= 1 << k;
  }
  return result;
} 
 
var As = [
  [1, 2, 3], // 2
  [1, 2, 10, 11, 18, 20], // 50
  [10, 26, 38, 44, 51, 70, 59, 20] // 182
];

for (let A of As){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(A));
  console.log(`DP, brute force: ${ f(A, 10) }, ${ bruteForce(A) }`);
  console.log('');
}

var numTests = 500;

for (let i=0; i<numTests; i++){
  const W = 8;
  const A = [];
  const n = 12;
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++){
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 << (W - 1)));
    A.push(num);
  }

  const fA = f(A, W);
  const brute = bruteForce(A);
  
  if (fA != brute){
    console.log('Mismatch:');
    console.log(A);
    console.log(fA, brute);
    console.log('');
  }
}

console.log("Done testing.");
```

Comment: Can u explain why we search for "l1-_A[i]" and "l2-_A[i]" in binary search?

Comment: @crazyCoder it may be possible to just use pointers but when I considered long sections of duplicates, it seemed simpler to me to implement the binary search. Complexity stays the same since we already had to sort in O(n log n).

Comment: I am sorry I asked it wrong.. but I think i got it.. My question was: In binary search why were we searching for "l1-_A[i]" and "l2-_A[i]". Correct me if I am wrong. We are doing it to get least index which will produce a sum between [ l1 , r1 ]. and later we calculate the total such indices as now we have the entire range. using "ptr1 - idx1 + 1"

Comment: @crazyCoder yes, I think you understood it correctly. (Watch the difference between the intervals, though. In one of them we exclude the upper bound.)